# change the button text in custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom

Hi i used this code to add button in custom module in magento admin.

I need to create a "Run Now" button and my code created a button without text. Like screenshot:

[image]

My question is : how to add "Run Now" text on button?

File: system.xml

```
<enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Module</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>

<module_btn translate="label">
                <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
                <label>Product Button</label>
                <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                <frontend_model>weo_productlist/adminhtml_system_config_button</frontend_model>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </module_btn>
```

Here is the code of /adminhtml_system_config_button file:

```
<?php
class Weo_Productlist_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Button extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{


protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {       
        $html = parent::_getElementHtml($element);
        $this->setElement($element);

        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                    ->setType('button')
                    ->setClass('scalable1')
                    ->setLabel('Run Now')
                    ->setOnClick("return callajaxRequestController();")
                    ->toHtml();


       return $html;





    }

}
```

Comment: i think change label value <label>Product Button</label>

Comment: @Yogesh its add label to button, not text on button.

Comment: @pooja add code of your `weo_productlist/adminhtml_system_config_button` file

Comment: @Piyush i updated the code of weo_productlist/adminhtml_system_config_button file.

Comment: @pooja check my answer and let me know if any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change button label you have to change `setLabel` value in file `Weo_Productlist_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Button`

```
$html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                    ->setType('button')
                    ->setClass('scalable1')
                    ->setLabel('Run Now') // change your label here
                    ->setOnClick("return callajaxRequestController();")
                    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: yes i did it. but by this code <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends> tag not working. i need to hide the button if "Enable Module" field value set to "No".
If i commented above code in "Weo_Productlist_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Button" file , button is shows without label.

Comment: @pooja that code is fine, if it is not working confirm the field name `<enabled>`. Also mark this answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: Please check my updated system.xml file code.

Comment: @pooja your code looks fine. is it displaying button when enabled is `No ` ?

Comment: yes @piyush....

Comment: @pooja unfortunately depends does not work for widget, check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18969/20064

Comment: thank you. i did it by adding an hidden field, Please check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65246/depend-not-working-in-system-xml